# UPDATE in mysql causes file path to be deleted if nothing is uploaded

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that uploads an image to my server and stores the path in MySQL. 
When I update a record the path to the uploaded image gets deleted from MySQL unless I select the image in the file upload box. I don't always need to update the image so how can I prevent the file path from being deleted if no file is selected on the update form? Also I am aware of SQL injection so no need to tell me PLEASE!

Here is the update form fields

```
        <fieldset id="info" class="auto-style1" style="height: 620px; width: 385px;">

        <legend id="infoLegend">Member Information</legend>

        <div id="InfoContent"> <table style="height: 598px; width: 383px;">
                <tbody>

                    <tr class="firstname">
                        <td class="firstname" style="width: 58px">First Name</td>
                        <td class="firstname" style="width: 280px">

                        <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $data2['first_name']?>" style="width: 170px"></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="lastname">
                        <td class="label" style="width: 58px">Last Name</td>
                        <td class="field" style="width: 280px">

                        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="lastname" value="<?php echo $data2['last_name']?>" style="width: 171px">
                        </td></tr>
                        <tr class="teamname">
                        <td class="teamname" style="width: 58px">Team Name</td>
                        <td class="teamname" style="width: 280px">

                        <input type="text"  name="team_name" id="teamname" value="<?php echo $data2['team_name']?>" style="width: 170px">
                        <br>
            </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="typeName">
                    <td class="label" style="width: 58px">Registration</td>
                    <td class="field" style="width: 280px">
                    <input type="text" name="registration" id="jerseybrand" value="<?php echo $data2['registration']?>" style="width: 170px">                       
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="paystatus">
                    <td class="paystatus" style="width: 58px">Payment Status</td>
                    <td class="paystatus" style="width: 280px">
                    <input type="text" name="pay_status" id="paystatus" value="<?php echo $data2['pay_status']?>" style="width: 170px">
                    <br>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="physical">
                    <td class="physical" style="width: 58px">Physical</td>
                    <td class="physical" style="width: 290px">
                    <input type="text" name="physical" id="physical" value="<?php echo $data2['physical']?>">
                    </tr style="width: 170px">
                    <tr class="photo">
                    <td class="photo" style="width: 58px">Photo Taken</td>
                    <td class="photo" style="width: 290px">
                    <input type="text" name="photo" id="photo" value="<?php echo $data2['photo']?>">
                    </tr style="width: 170px">

                    <tr>
                    <td>
                    Notes
                    </td>
                    <td class="notes" style="width: 280px">
                    <textarea name="notes" id="notes" class="auto-style1" style="height: 35px; width: 215px"><?php echo $data2['notes']?></textarea>
                    <br><br>
                    </td></tr>
                    <tr class="teamlogo">
                    <td class="teamlogo" style="width: 58px">Team Logo</td>
                    <td class="teamlogo" style="width: 280px">
                    <img name="logo_image "src="<?php echo $data2['logo_src']?>" id="logoimage" height="100" width="100">
                    </td width="116">

                    <input type="hidden" name="logo_src" value="<?php echo $data2['logo_src']?>" id="logosrc"/>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="logosrc">
                        <td class="logosrc" style="width: 58px">Change Logo</td>
                        <td class="logosrc" style="width: 280px">

                        <select name="team_name" id="dd" onChange="swapImage()" style="width: 150px">
    <option value="" title="logos/cheerlogoleft.jpg">SELECT</option>
    <option value="COUGARS" title="logos/cougars2013.jpg" >Cougars</option>
    <option value="FALCONS" title="logos/falcons2013.jpg" >Falcons</option>
    <option value="GREEN VALLEY KNIGHTS" title="logos/gvklogo2013.png">Green Valley Knights</option>
    <option value="LONGHORNS" title="logos/longhorns2013.jpg">Longhorns</option>
    <option value="MUSTANGS" title="logos/mustangs2013.jpg">Mustangs</option>
        <option value="NW NINERS" title="logos/nwniners2013.jpg">NW Niners</option>
        <option value="REBELS" title="logos/rebels2013.jpg">Rebels</option>
        <option value="WILDCATS" title="logos/wildcats2013.jpg">Wildcats</option>
</select>

</td> 
                    </tr>
<tr class="photo">
                    <td class="photo" style="width: 58px">Change Photo</td>
                    <td class="photo" style="width: 290px">
                    <input type="file" name="member_photo" "id="cheerphoto"/>
                    </tr style="width: 170px">

            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            </fieldset>

    </td><td id="righttdhw" style="width: 517px; height: 141px;">
        <fieldset id="info" style="width: 260px; height: 183px">

        <legend id="infoLegend">Member Photo</legend>

        <div id="memberphoto"> 
        <table style="height: 156px; width: 260px;">
        <tbody>
                <tr class="memberphoto">
                   <td class="field" style="width: 269px; height: 132px; text-align: center;">
                    <img name="member_photo" src="<?php echo $data2['member_photo']?>" id="memberphoto" height="150" width="250" >

                    </td>
                  </tr>
```

and the process_edit.php file

```
<?php
$id=$_POST['id'];
//This is the directory where images will be uploaded and saved
$target = "uploads/cheer/";
$target = $target . basename($_FILES['member_photo']['name']);

//This gets all the form data//

//----------MEMBER INFO----------//
$team_name=!empty($_POST['team_name'])? $_POST['team_name'] : '';
$first_name=!empty($_POST['first_name'])? $_POST['first_name'] : '';
$last_name=!empty($_POST['last_name'])? $_POST['last_name'] : '';
$registration=!empty($_POST['registration'])? $_POST['registration'] : '';
$pay_status=!empty($_POST['pay_status'])? $_POST['pay_status'] : '';
$physical=!empty($_POST['physical'])? $_POST['physical'] : '';
$photo=!empty($_POST['photo'])? $_POST['photo'] : '';
$notes=!empty($_POST['notes'])? $_POST['notes'] : '';
$logo_src=!empty($_POST['logo_src'])? $_POST['logo_src'] : '';

//----------IMAGES----------//
$pic=!empty($_FILES['member_photo']['name'])? $_FILES['member_photo']['name'] : '';

//----------CONNECT TO DATABASE----------//
include 'elite_connect.php';

//----------WRITES DATA TO DATABASE----------//
mysql_query("UPDATE cheer SET team_name='$team_name', first_name='$first_name', last_name='$last_name', registration='$registration', pay_status='$pay_status', physical='$physical', photo='$photo', logo_src='$logo_src', notes='$notes', member_photo='$target' 
WHERE `id` = '$id'");
//----------DISPLAYS MYSQL ERRORS----------//
print_r($_POST);
echo mysql_error();
//----------WRITES PHOTO TO SERVER----------//
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['member_photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{
//----------TELLS IF ALL IS OK----------//
echo "The file ". basename($_FILES['member_photo']['name']). "has been uploaded!";
}
else {
//----------GIVES AN ERROR IF IT'S NOT----------//
?><br/><?php
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your image.";
}
?>
```

Comment: I'd be more worried about the gaping glaring [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) holes in the code before worrying about a few fields getting trashed. The utter lack of ANY error handling on the DB calls and the lack of success checking on the file upload is very bad as well.

Comment: @MarcB Really? I don't really care about any of that, are you going to come into my office and take my laptop that MySQL is running on and that this form is only used on which also never goes on the web and do an sql injection attack? seriously I said I don't care about it.

Comment: I don't see your input field for 'member_photo ?

Comment: @FabienTheSolution it's in there just a little below the middle of the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach instead. This will update your DB only if the file is uploaded correctly :

```
//----------CONNECT TO DATABASE----------//
include 'elite_connect.php';  

//----------WRITES DATA TO DATABASE----------//
mysql_query("UPDATE cheer SET team_name='$team_name', first_name='$first_name', last_name='$last_name', registration='$registration', pay_status='$pay_status', physical='$physical', photo='$photo', logo_src='$logo_src', notes='$notes'
WHERE `id` = '$id'");
//----------DISPLAYS MYSQL ERRORS----------//
print_r($_POST);
echo mysql_error();
//----------WRITES PHOTO TO SERVER----------//
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['member_photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{
//----------TELLS IF ALL IS OK----------//
echo "The file ". basename($_FILES['member_photo']['name']). "has been uploaded!";
mysql_query("UPDATE cheer SET member_photo='$target' 
WHERE `id` = '$id'");
}
else {
//----------GIVES AN ERROR IF IT'S NOT----------//
?><br/><?php
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your image.";
}
```

Comment: Fabulous, simple, quick and it works. Thanks for keeping on topic and not going the sql injection route!

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning and inserting $target regardless of it is actually being sent.  You need to check to see if a file is being sent (like you are doing with the normal input fields) before inserting it.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php

From there you can either do a conditional insert, one insert that includes the file one that doesn't or include a hidden field that stores the url as a value and simply swap that in if an image hasn't been uploaded.